# How do you get rid of the scrollbars in AS3, Feathers. SCROLL_BAR_DISPLAY_MODE_NONE not working

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll, scrollbar, starling-framework

I have a TextArea where I print out lots of stuff. Becuase i print every message on a new line the TextArea needs scrollbars. I want to be able to scroll but i dont wanna see scrollbars. I don't want any scrollbars because they dont fit in with my program and they increase my draw calls.

i tried:

```
SCROLL_BAR_DISPLAY_MODE_NONE
```

This got rid of the scrollbars and the scrolling with it. With this i can still scroll, but the TextArea will then only scroll if I add stuff to it. So that's not really working for me.

I just wanna be able to scroll without any(visible) scrollbars.

Here is my TextArea code:

```
private var Text:TextArea = new TextArea();

Text.y = stage.stageHeight - 355;
Text.height = 340;
Text.width = 1320;
Text.x = 15;
Text.isEditable = false;
Text.hasElasticEdges = true;
Text.text = welcomeText;
```

Answer (score 0):

set "verticalScrollPolicy" and "horizontalScrollPolicy" to off in your textarea. xou can still scroll using mouse scroller or by arrows, but scrollbars won't be visible. in mxml it looks like this:

```
<s:TextArea verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"/>
```

in action script it would look like this:

```
var text:TextArea = new TextArea();
text.setStyle("verticalScrollPolicy", ScrollPolicy.OFF);
text.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", ScrollPolicy.OFF);
```

I'm using spark TextArea container. simple app code for tests above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="onCC()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:VBox id="container">
        <s:Label text="type here:" />
        <s:TextArea id="source"  width="100" height="50"/>
        <s:Label text="and text will appear in this noneditable field below" />
    </mx:VBox>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

            import flashx.textLayout.container.ScrollPolicy;
            private function onCC():void{
                var text:TextArea = new TextArea();
                text.width = 100;
                text.height = 50;
                text.editable = false;
                text.setStyle("verticalScrollPolicy", ScrollPolicy.OFF);
                text.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", ScrollPolicy.OFF);
                source.addEventListener(TextOperationEvent.CHANGE, function(e:Event):void{
                    text.text = source.text;
                });
                container.addElement(text);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I'm no able to scroll when i set is to OFF.

Comment: i've tried this at my own. if you click on textarea to set it's focus and then scroll (or use arrows) it works like charm. but you can also make onvisible scroller skin

Comment: where should I change it then? i changed textArea.verticalScrollPolicy = ScrollContainer.SCROLL_POLICY_AUTO; to textArea.verticalScrollPolicy = ScrollContainer.SCROLL_POLICY_OFF; in my theme .as file

Comment: in my knowlege vertical and scroll policies are styles, not properties, and my flash buil;der (4.7) didn't permit me to acces textArea.verticalScrollPolicy like variable. i've been doing it by
setStyle("verticalScrollPolicy", ScrollPolicy.OFF);

i'll edite my answer to add action script code

Comment: I tried the ActionScript code in flashbuilder, it didn't work. There is no setStyle().

Comment: what flash builder version and SDK version you use? do you use spark TextArea or mx one? i've placed full code of my test app which works for me, so i'm bit confused about you'r faliure.

Comment: Flashbuilder 4.6, flex 10 i believe. i use Feathers textarea

Comment: my first google atempt succeded in page, which sets scrollBarDisplayMode to SCROLL_BAR_DISPLAY_MODE_NONE. source: http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/text-area in "Customizing Scrolling Behavior". according to this scrolloing polisies should be auto. hope it helps